# Complement of zero set of holomorphic function is dense and connected

Tags: general-topology, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

This is exercise 1.1.8 of Huybrechts' *Complex Geometry*.

**Problem**: let $U$ be an open connected subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$. Let $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function. Show that the complement of the zero set $U\setminus Z(f)$ is dense and connected.

For the density I have reasoned as follows: $Z(f)=f^{-1}(\{0\})$ which is closed. Thus $U\setminus Z(f)$ is open. For it to be dense as a subset of $U$ I need only construct sequences $\{x_n\}\subset U\setminus Z(f)$ converging to a fixed but arbitrary point in $Z(f)$. This would follow probably form the identity principle, but I have reasoned with Weierstrass Preparation Theorem: after a suitable change of coordinates, I can consider $f$ to be set at the origin, and there must be some coordinate $z_1$ such that $f(z_1,0,\dots,0)\not\equiv 0$. Near the origin I have a decomposition
$$
f = h \cdot p
$$
where $p$ is a Weierstrass polynomial in $z_1$ and $h(0,...,0)\neq 0$. Zeroes of a single-variable polynomial are necessarily isolated (since we assumed $f(z_1,*)$ is not trivial), so that immediately gives me a sequence.

For showing that $U\setminus Z(f)$ is connected, I have barely any idea. I suppose that I could use something like $Z(f)$ has at least codimension 1 in some sense, and that gives me 1 complex dimension = 2 real dimensions to carry out paths from "one side of $Z(f)$ to the other", loosely speaking.

I would appreciate any hint and correction on both these issues.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/914713 for connectedness.

Comment: I did check that but only one part is proved. They suggest using the Riemann extension theorem to construct such sets $A$ and $B$ but nothing is explicitly said about that technique in the question or answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to assume that $f$ is not identically zero. Here is one way to argue:

Step 1. I will start with some general topology observations. Let $X$ be a topological space and $A\subset X$ a subset. One says that *$A$ does not locally separate $X$* if for every $x\in X$ there is a neighbourhood $W_x$ of $x$ in $X$ such that $W_x\setminus A$ is connected.

I will now assume, mostly for convenience, that $X$ is metrizable. (In the case of interest, $X$ will be an open subset of ${\mathbb C}^n$.)

**Lemma.** Suppose that $X$ is connected, $A\subset X$ is closed, $int(A)=\emptyset$ and $A$ does not locally separate $X$. Then $X\setminus A$ is connected.

Proof. Let $V$ be a connected component of $X\setminus A$. I claim that $cl_X(V)=X$. If not, then, by connectedness of $X$, there is a boundary point $x$ of $cl_X(V)$ in $X$, and, hence, a sequence
$x_i\in X\setminus cl(V)$ converging to $x$. Since $A$ is closed and has empty interior in $X$, the sequence $x_i$ can be chosen so that $x_i\notin A$ for each $i$. Let $W_x$ denote a neighborhood of $x$ such that
$W_x\setminus A$ is connected. Since $x$ is in the closure of $V$, the intersection $W_x\cap V\subset W_x\setminus A$ is also nonempty. Furthermore, for some $i$, $x_i$ is in $W_x\setminus A$. By the connectedness of $W_x\setminus A$, it follows that $x_i$ lies in the connected component $V$ of $X\setminus A$.  A contradiction.

Thus, $cl_X(V)=X$. Since $cl_X(V)\subset V \cup A$ (as $V$ is a connected component of $X\setminus A$), it follows that $X=V\cup A$, i.e.  $X\setminus A$ is connected. **qed**

I will now turn to your question.

Let $X$ be an open connected subset of  ${\mathbb C}^n$, $f: X\to {\mathbb C}$ a **nonconstant** holomorphic function, $A:= f^{-1}(0)$. I will be using the fact that $A$ has empty interior in $X$ (already proven).

Step 2. Now, prove that $A$ does not locally separate $X$. Namely, given $x\in X$, take $W_x$ to be an open ball  centered at $x$ and contained in $X$. Verify connectedness of $W_x\setminus A$ by looking at the intersections of complex lines $L$ with $W_x$: For each pair of distinct points $p, q$ in $W_x\setminus A$ take the complex line $L$ containing $p, q$. Then $f|_{L\cap X}$ is nonconstant, i.e. $L\cap A$ is a discrete subset of $L\cap X$. (I will leave it to you as an exercise.) From this, conclude path-connectedness of  $L\cap (W_x\setminus A)$ and, hence, path-connectedness of $W_x\setminus A$. (Again, an exercise.)

3. Now, combine Lemma and and Step 2 to conclude that the zero-level set of a nonconstant holomorphic function does not separate the domain, as required.

Comment: I do understand the rest of the proof, but the lemma still puzzles me. Where can I find a reference for a step by step proof of your Lemma?

Comment: @topolosaurus: I do not have a reference for this. Which step was unclear?

Comment: how about for the density? @MoisheKohan

Comment: @HossienSahebjame: Hint: Show that $A$ has empty interior.

Comment: @MoisheKohan so in this context, show $U \setminus Z(f)$ has empty interior? could I go about it by contradiction? supposing there exists an element in the interior..

Comment: @HossienSahebjame: If you read my answer, $A=Z(f)$, so you have to prove that $Z(f)$ has empty interior, not its complement. If you do not know how to prove this, first think about the 1-variable case. Once you come up with a proof, you will see that it also works in higher dimensions.

Comment: So going toward a contradiction, we suppose there is some $z_0 \in \text{int}Z(f)$, then there exists $\epsilon=(\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_n)$ with $\epsilon_j >0$ for $1 \leq j \leq n$ such that $B_\epsilon(z_0) \subset Z(f)$? is this correct thus far @MoisheKohan but $Z(f)=\{z : f(z) = 0\}$, I can't see the contradiction however. Is it because the $z \in Z(f)$ get mapped to zero so you can't have epsilon polydisks contained inside it? Also, is $z_0=(z_1,...,z_n)$?

Answer (score 0):

We want to show that for any $z\in Z(f)$ there exists a sequence in its conplement converging to it. Suppose that it was false, then we would be able to find $\epsilon>0$, such that $B_\epsilon(0)$ contains no points from the complement of $Z(f)$. Therefore, $f$ vanishes on some open subset of $U$ and by generalized Identity Theorem, it follows that $f$ must vanish on whole of $U$, thus contradicting our assumption.

Let me know if this has any mistakes.