# complement of connected set with respect to zero set is connected

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

Let $U \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be open and connected. Show for any non-trivial holomorphic map $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, the complement $U \setminus Z(f)$ is connected and dense in $U$.

So to show connected, suppose towards a contradiction that $U \setminus Z(f)$ is disconnected, then

$$U \setminus Z(f) = A \cup B \subset U$$

where $A \cap B = \emptyset$ and $A,B$ are both noon-empty, open and thus both closed.

But since $U$ is connected, then $A \subset U$ or $B \subset U$ (this I can prove) thus WLOG say $B = \emptyset$ a contradiction thus $U \setminus Z(f)$ is connected. To show it is dense, we must show it is countable and $\overline{U \setminus Z(f)} = U$. So if $a \in U \setminus Z(f)$, does this imply $f(a) \neq 0$? How do I get that the closure is all of $U$?

Here, $Z(f)$ denotes the zero set of $f$.

Comment: This was asked at least twice in the past.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [complement of zero set of holomorphic function is connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/914713/complement-of-zero-set-of-holomorphic-function-is-connected) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4251976/complement-of-zero-set-of-holomorphic-function-is-dense-and-connected?rq=1).

Comment: @MoisheKohan thank you so much!!